# Pandas query error when column is an integer

Tags: python, pandas

I have a dataset similar to this

```
Location    Name
129         Hospital A
130         Hospital B
105         Hospital C
```

I am trying to query to get only the rows with location 129

I am trying to use following code:

```
df.query('Location == 129')
```

I get an invalid syntax error. I do not get these errors if the column contains a string.

Update: 
I apologize the error was being generated because my location label was Location ID

```
Location ID    Name
    129         Hospital A
    130         Hospital B
    105         Hospital C
```

It looks like having spaces in column names gives that error.

Comment: Your code runs fine with pandas 0.20.3. What is your version? It seems like a bug.

Comment: it is ok on my side

Comment: Sorry, the location column is called Location ID. I notice that when used query with labels that have space on it it gives that error

Comment: See discussion on this open issue: https://github.com/pandas-dev/pandas/issues/6508

Answer (score 4):

You can use columns with spaces on `query` in Pandas if you [reference them with backticks](https://github.com/pandas-dev/pandas/issues/6508).

```py
df.query('`Location ID` == 129')
```

Answer (score 2):

[`query`](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.DataFrame.query.html) can be very picky in terms of syntax.

The short answer here is that any column name that you couldn't reference in "attribute style" (`name_of_dataframe.column_name`), you also can't reference in `query`.  In this case, `df.Location ID` would be invalid.

As an alternative, just use boolean filtering:

```
df[df['Location ID'] == 129]
```